# Can scp create a directory if it doesn't exist?

Tags: scp

I want to use `scp` to upload files but sometimes the target directory may not exist.

Is it possible to create the folder automatically? If so, how? If not, what alternative way can I try?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

This is one of the many things that [`rsync`](https://rsync.samba.org/) can do.

If you're using a version of `rsync` released in the past several years,¹ its basic command syntax is similar to `scp`:²

```
$ rsync -r local-dir remote-machine:path
```

That will copy `local-source` and its contents to `$HOME/path/local-dir` on the remote machine, creating whatever directories are required.³

`rsync` does have some restrictions here that can affect whether this will work in your particular situation. It won't create multiple levels of missing remote directories, for example; it will only create up to one missing level on the remote. You can easily get around this by preceding the `rsync` command with something like this:

```
$ ssh remote-host 'mkdir -p foo/bar/qux'
```

That will create the `$HOME/foo/bar/qux` tree if it doesn't exist. It won't complain or do anything else bad if it *does* already exist.

`rsync` sometimes has other surprising behaviors. Basically, you're asking it to figure out what you meant to copy, and its guesses may not match your assumptions. Try it and see. If it doesn't behave as you expect and you can't see why, post more details about your local and remote directory setups, and give the command you tried.

---

**Footnotes**:

1. Before `rsync` 2.6.0 (1 Jan 2004), it required the `-e ssh` flag to make it behave like `scp` because it defaulted to the obsolete [RSH protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell).
2. `scp` and `rsync` share some flags, but there is only a bit of overlap.
3. When using `SSH` as the transfer protocol, `rsync` uses the same defaults. So, just like `scp`, it will assume there is a user with the same name as your local user on the remote machine by default.

Comment: I am using Mac OSX, do I need to install rsync on both local and remote side?

Comment: searched `rsync`'s documentation page, did not find how to use ssh-key to login. I don't want to use username/password to login

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: Mac OS X ships with `rsync`. And yes, you do need `rsync` on the remote side, too, just like with `scp`. As for SSH keys, `rsync` is actually using SSH underneath with the default `-e ssh`, so if you have keys set up for use with `scp`, they will work for `rsync` as well.

Comment: @WarrenYoung `-r` makes no difference. The scenario you describe only works if you are copying a directory and if the target parent directory exists. So, `rsync foo/ u@h:~/` will create the target directory `foo` but `rsync foo/ u@h:~/bar/` will not create the target directory `bar`. That one will create `bar/foo` only if `bar/` exists. In any case, the OP is uploading files and even in the cases where this works, it only works for entire directories.

Comment: @terdon: I just tried it here, and it works as I said. I have version 2.6.9 on the local machine and 3.1.0 on the remote. I said `rsync -r local-dir remote.host.example.com:boo`, and found `boo/local-dir` on the remote after an error-free transfer. `boo` did not exist before this.

Comment: @terdon: After some more experimentation, it appears to work for only a single directory level, and not with plain files. If you try `rsync -r local-file remote.example.com:something` and `something` is not a preexisting directory, it will assume you mean to do a file copy with a new name on the remote. When I tried to create more than one level of missing directories, I got a strange protocol error from `rsync`, though that may be due to the large mismatch in version numbers between my local and remote systems.

Comment: Yes, I've been playing with it too. It seems like specifying a file name also makes it fail. So `rsync file host:/foo/file` fails if `foo/` doesn't exist but `rsync file host:/foo/` creates the directory and places `file` in it. Strange. Anyway, you're quite right and the basic scenario works, I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: @WarrenYoung thanks, I have multiple keys on the remote side so I use `scp -i ~/.ssh/particular-key` to upload. What is the command for `rsync`?

Comment: @WarrenYoung one more question is that my local rsync is 2.6.9 while on the remote it's 3.0.9 - how do I upgrade my client side? (Mac OSX)

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: Multiple keys on the *remote* side makes no sense. If the remote side will accept many keys and your default *local* key is one of them, then you don't need any special options. If you have multiple *local* keys and your default key won't work to get you into the remote machine, then you pass the `ssh -i` command to `rsync -e`, like `rsync -e 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/some-other-key' ...`.

Comment: typo. on local, not remote.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: Regarding upgrading the Mac OS X version of `rsync`, I just successfully did it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), saying `brew install homebrew/dupes/rsync`. However, doing so did not allow me to create 2+ levels of missing directories. See my edited answer for a coping strategy.

Answer (score 76):

If you are copying a group of files, not really. If you are copying a directory and all the contents below it, yes. Given this command:

```
$ scp -pr /source/directory user@host:the/target/directory
```

If `directory` does not exist in `~/the/target` on `host`, it will be created. If, however, `~the/target` does not exist, you will likely have issues - I don't remember the exact results of this case, but be prepared for the intended `scp` to fail.

Comment: `scp: /home/madmike/test_bin: No such file or directory` As soon as the target directory is missing this breaks on my setup. Using cygwin on the client and RHEL 6.9 on the server. What is your setup?

Comment: @John, the same issue either with relative path or absolute.

Comment: From `man scp`: `-p    Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since the OP asks how to do this with `scp`. The accepted answer does not answer the question of "how can I do this with scp?". Furthermore, from a practical POV, the accepted answer also failed for me when I was trying to do this on a machine that had rsync disabled (synology).

Answer (score 36):

As far as I know, `scp` itself cannot do that, no. However, you could just `ssh` to the target machine, create the directory and then copy. Something like:

```
ssh user@host "mkdir -p /target/path/" &&
    scp /path/to/source user@host:/target/path/
```

Note that if you are copying entire directories, the above is not needed. For example, to copy the directory `~/foo` to the remote host, you could use the `-r` (recursive) flag:

```
scp -r ~/foo/ user@host:~/
```

That will create the target directory `~/foo` on the remote host. However, it can't create the parent directory. `scp ~/foo user@host:~/bar/foo` will fail unless the target directory `bar` exists. In any case, the `-r` flag won't help create a target directory if you are copying individual files.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following function before transferring `btrfs` snapshots over `ssh`:

```
check_remote_dir() {
        printf "\ntesting remote directory: '$1' "

        if ssh -p $PORT $ROOT@$REMOTE "[ ! -d $1 ]"; then
                printf "\nCreating: $1 on $ROOT@$REMOTE\n"
                ssh -p $PORT $ROOT@$REMOTE "mkdir -p $1"
        else
                printf "[OK]\n"
        fi
}
```

Just call the function in your script with:

`check_remote_dir /my/remote/path`

Comment: I do pretty much the same thing, but I have to type in the password manually (for security reasons), so I end up typing it in at least twice...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. According to scp's man page:

> **man scp**
>
> .....
>
> -r      Recursively copy entire directories.  Note that scp follows symâ
>                bolic links encountered in the tree traversal.
>
> ....

Comment: That will not create the target parent directory. It can copy a directory to an existing location. So, `scp -r foo/ u@h:~/bar` will create `bar/foo` if the remote `bar/` exists but will fail if it doesn't.

Comment: It won't fail. It will copy `foo` contents to the new directory `/bar`. Of course the name has been changed which may not be what the OP wants. If what you want is a new tree structure created in the destination machine then `scp` won't do the job, if what you want is to replicate a tree structure from a certain branch in the tree then that structure is created.

Comment: Yes, but this only works if you are copying _directories_, not files. `scp -r file host:~/bar/` won't create `bar/`.

Answer (score 1):

When restricted to only scp or sftp with no ssh available (by rssh), it is possible to create directories by copying empty directory tree with rsync and then copying files.

That is how I put public ssh key to remote host when ssh-copy-id does not work and .ssh directory does not exists:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p22' -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" ~/.ssh backup@1.2.3.4:~/
scp -P22 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub backup@1.2.3.4:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

It is possible to combine this commands into one rsync adding one more include filter in the middle, if target file name is the same.

Answer (score 1):

### How about "smart" scp + ssh mkdir?

This is a script to create target directory hierarchy **only once** per directory (not a blind `ssh mkdir -p` each time).

#### Rationale

I'm copying motion recordings (video files) as they are written to local disk (event-driven).

- `rsync` doesn't make sense because there is no point in doing full directory comparisons - I am transferring one file per event.  If I restrict rsync to just one subdir or file, then it won't be able to create the full target directory hierarchy.
- `scp` will work great but it doesn't know if the target directory exists, and I don't want to run an **ssh mkdir -p** for every file.

#### Solution

1. Create each target dir via ssh the first time there is a need (first time we are about to copy into it).
2. Cache target dir name in a an array so that we won't `ssh mkdir` each time we see it again.  Clear this array daily so that it doesn't get huge.
3. scp the file.

#### Example code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

TARGETHOST="some.hostname"
TARGETPATH="/data/backups/MOTION/"

ensure_dir() {
    if [ "$TODAY" != "$(date +%D)" ] ; then
        CREATED=()  # reset array daily and first time so it won't get huge
        TODAY=$(date +%D)
    fi  
    if [[ ! " ${CREATED[@]} " =~ " ${1} " ]]; then
        # create dir
        echo "Creating remote directory: $1"
        ssh $TARGETHOST "mkdir -p ${TARGETPATH}$1"
        CREATED+=("$1")
    fi  
}

# This line is specific to my use case, watching a directory for new files:
inotifywait -mr --format '%w %f' -e close_write --exclude '.jpg' /data/MOTION/ | while read filedir filename ; do
    RELDIR=$(echo $filedir | sed 's|/data/MOTION/||')
    ensure_dir "$RELDIR"
    echo "Copying '$filename' from '${filedir}' to '${RELDIR}'"
    scp -r -p "${filedir}${filename}" "${TARGETHOST}:${TARGETPATH}${RELDIR}${filename}"
done
```

#### Typical output, illustrating "smart" mkdir behavior:

```bsh
Creating remote directory: 2019-12-28/movie-C6/
Copying 'test1.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C6/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C6/'
Creating remote directory: 2019-12-28/movie-C4/
Copying '095700.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C4/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C4/'
Copying '095841.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C4/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C4/'
Copying '100410.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C4/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C4/'
Creating remote directory: 2019-12-28/movie-C2/
Copying '102106.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C2/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C2/'
Creating remote directory: 2019-12-28/movie-C5/
Copying '102318.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C5/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C5/'
Copying '102326.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C2/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C2/'
Creating remote directory: 2019-12-28/movie-C1/
Copying '102450.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C1/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C1/'
Copying '102744.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C2/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C2/'
Copying '103008.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C2/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C2/'
Copying '103945.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C6/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C6/'
Copying '104252.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C6/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C6/'
Copying '104824.mp4' from '/data/MOTION/2019-12-28/movie-C6/' to '2019-12-28/movie-C6/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the command with the mkdir command and then reference to the folder you've created:

```
mkdir ~/new-folder/ && scp -P 22 <remote/url>:~/new-folder/
```

Comment: (1) The question says “automatically”.   This does not appear to be automatic.   (2) This appears to be only a trivial variation on [terdon’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193368/80216#193372).